# Does this conditional css loading for IE7 and lower work for IE8 in compability mode?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, conditional-statements

Does this conditional css loading for IE7 and lower work for IE8 in compability mode?

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Only one way to find out, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx -> This clearly says compatibility view is to force IE8 render a page like IE-7.

If you have installed IE developer toolbar ( [Install and use IE developer toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd443295%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ), you can check if the CSS is used while rendering OR run the script @ [Detect Browser](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) in compatibility mode to check which browser you're hitting.