# CSS | What is this conditional CSS and where can I look for more documentation about it?

Tags: css

I was reading through this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@Florian/freebie-google-material-design-shadow-helper-2a0501295a2d#.lhgcg8trt). In one of the examples, there's a CSS class definition like:

```
**
 * A mixin which helps you to add depth to elements according to the Google Material Design spec:
 * http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/layout-principles.html#layout-principles-dimensionality
 *
 * Please note that the values given in the specification cannot be used as is. To create the same visual experience
 * the blur parameter has to be doubled.
 *
 * Author: Florian Kutschera (@gefangenimnetz), Conceptboard GmbH (@conceptboardapp)
 *
 * Example usage:
 *
 * .card {
 *     width: 95px;
 *     height: 95px;
 *     background: #f4f4f4;
 *     -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
 *     -moz-transition: all 250ms;
 *     transition: all 250ms;
 *     .BoxShadowHelper(1);
 *     &:hover {
 *         .BoxShadowHelper(3);
 *         -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
 *         -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
 *         transform: translateY(-5px);
 *     }
 * }
 *
 */

.BoxShadowHelper(@level: 1){
    & when (@level = 1) {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    }
    & when (@level = 2) {
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }
    & when (@level = 3) {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }
    & when (@level = 4) {
        box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    }
    & when (@level = 5) {
        box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    }
}
```

I...well, didn't know we could do that with classes. I've tried looking for more information, but "CSS conditional logic" didn't pull up anything. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453257/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-symbol-in-css) on here, about the @ symbol, but when I looked for [more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule), it didn't seem relevant to this code snippet.

"Conditional CSS" brings up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553955/how-to-write-conditional-css), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759864/does-this-conditional-css-loading-for-ie7-and-lower-work-for-ie8-in-compability), and more questions about including stylesheets for IE.

I'd just like to know what I'm looking at in .BoxShadowHelper and .card and where I can learn more about it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910667/how-to-use-if-statements-in-less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not *vanilla* CSS, this is LESS.

Specifically, those `@level = 1` are `LESS' Guard Comparison Operators`. See documentation here http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-guard-comparison-operators